# Iterate over parameters without a loop

Tags: python, functional-programming

I need to iterate over two lists of numbers which form the inputs to a function. I'd like to do this in a functional way. Currently I'm doing:

```
results = []
for i in params_list1:
    for j in params_list2:
      results.append(myfunction(i,j))
```

where `myfunction()` returns a number. I'm pretty sure there is a way to multiply `params_list1` and `params_list2` (maybe using numpy broadcasting?) and map them to `myfunction()`, but I'm not able to figure it out. Any tips?

Comment: Could you please post sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format __as text__, so one could use it when coding) and describe what do you want to do with the input data in order to get output data set? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think OP is asking for ways to get and iterate over Cartesian products.

Comment: @MaxU I think the *mcve* is in the question

Comment: @user3100115, well, depending on OP's `myfunction()` it might be possible or not to work with vectorized data, which is usually __much__ faster compared to looping solutions. But it's difficult to say not being able to see what OP wants to do with his data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to do this, also you should consider to use list comprehensions or `map` (if you need lazy evaluation) instead of using using `list.append`:

```
results = []
for i, j in itertools.product(params_list1, params_list2):
    results.append(myfunction(i, j))
```

or using  `map` like this:

```
result = map(function(i, j)  for i, j in itertools.product(params_list1, params_list2))
```

You can also use the `*` expression in Python3.x to unpack a *list* of arguments:

```
result = [myfunction(*item) for item in itertools.product(params_list1, params_list2)]
```

Comment: ahh itertools.product. I was thinking numpy broadcasting, but this works!

Comment: Argument unpacking (`f(*args, **kwargs)`) also works in Python 2.x

Answer (score 1):

numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np

In [261]: a = np.array([0,1,2,3])

In [262]: b = np.array([2,3,4])

In [263]:

In [263]: np.dstack(np.meshgrid(a, b)).reshape(-1, 2)
Out[263]:
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

Answer (score -3):

`map(myfunction, params_list1,params_list2)`

Comment: This is just equivalent to `zip()` or worse. OP needs Cartesian products.

Comment: I had misread the question. There's no delete option on the stack app.